# How to make double MouseArea take effect?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.5

Here is my QML code :

```
Rectangle
{
    .....
    Rectangle
    {
        ....height and width is smaller than parent
        MouseArea
        {
            id: mouseArea2
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true

            onEntered:
            {
                console.log("enter 2")
            }
        }
    }


    MouseArea
    {
        id: mouseArea1
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onEntered:
        {
            console.log("enter 1")
        }
    }
}
```

Only `mouseArea1` takes effect. If I remove `mouseArea1` then `mouseArea2` takes effect. So I think the mouse event must be handled by `mouseArea1` and let it couldn't be passed to `mouseArea2`.

I search the document to find out which attr can prevent such behavior but nothing found. So how to let the `mouseArea1` and `mouseArea2` take effect at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For "composed" mouse events -- `clicked`, `doubleClicked` and `pressAndHold` -- you can achieve this using the [`propagateComposedEvents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop) property.  But that won't work here because hover events are not composed events.

So what you need to do instead is to change the order in which the `MouseArea`s are evaluated.

One simple trick is to swap the order of the two `MouseArea`s in the QML source itself. By placing the smaller one after the larger one, the smaller one takes precedence:

```
Rectangle{
    //.....
    MouseArea{
        id: mouseArea1
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onEntered:{
            console.log("enter 1")
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
         //....height and width is smaller than parent
        MouseArea{
            id: mouseArea2
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true

            onEntered:{
                console.log("enter 2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A second method that achieves the same thing is to add a `z` index to the topmost `MouseArea` that's greater than the lower one.  By default every element has a `z` index of `0`, so just adding `z: 1` to the smaller `MouseArea` will do the trick:

```
Rectangle{
    //.....
    Rectangle{
        //....height and width is smaller than parent
        MouseArea{
            z: 1              // <-----------------
            id: mouseArea2
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true

            onEntered:{
                console.log("enter 2")
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea{
        id: mouseArea1
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onEntered:{
            console.log("enter 1")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in the documentation. Take for instance the following QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    color: "yellow"
    width: 100; height: 100

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: console.log("clicked yellow")
    }

    Rectangle {
        color: "blue"
        width: 50; height: 50

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            propagateComposedEvents: true
            onClicked: {
                console.log("clicked blue")
                mouse.accepted = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the yellow `Rectangle` contains a blue Rectangle. The latter is the top-most item in the hierarchy of the visual stacking order; it will visually rendered above the former.

Since the blue `Rectangle` sets `propagateComposedEvents` to `true`, and also sets `MouseEvent::accepted` to `false` for all received clicked events, any clicked events it receives are propagated to the `MouseArea` of the yellow rectangle beneath it.

Clicking on the blue `Rectangle` will cause the `onClicked` handler of its child `MouseArea` to be invoked; the event will then be propagated to the `MouseArea` of the yellow `Rectangle`, causing its own `onClicked` handler to be invoked.