# Qt Quick: How to handle hover-type events in MouseArea, yet let lower-z MouseAreas handle them too?

Tags: qt, event-handling, qml, mouseevent, qtquick2

If, on my MouseArea, I've enabled the property `hoverEnabled`, I'm notified of the `entered` signal, even if no mouse button is held at that time (just as I want).

But then a lower-z MouseArea will not receive positionChanged events on the first MouseArea's space, since they're eaten up by the first MouseArea.

[The Qt docs on `positionChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#positionChanged-signal) specifically say this:

> When handling this signal, changing the accepted property of the mouse parameter has no effect.

Example code:

```
Item {
    width: 100
    height: 100

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onPositionChanged: {
            console.log("MouseArea 1");
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onEntered: {
            console.log("MouseArea 2");
        }
    }
}
```

"MouseArea 1" is never printed. I want both strings to be printed.

**Is there a way to do it?**

*Related question note:* [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666001/how-to-make-double-mousearea-take-effect) is very similar but the asker there has 2 differently-sized overlapping `MouseArea`s, and he wants the smaller one (which is has higher z) to eat up events when the events fall within both. I want both overlapping `MouseArea`s to handle events that fall within both.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, it doesn't look like this is possible, most likely because an implementation detail limitation. Normally, it is effortless to propagate events, what you need is to `propagateComposedEvents: true` and to `mouse.accepted = false` in the handler.

However, while that works as expected for clicks, it doesn't work for `onEntered`. My first thought was that it was the lack of the `mouse` signal parameter for the `entered` signal, however `positionChanged` has it but it still doesn't work as expected, as the documentation says, it has no effect. And that's actually true for `positionChanged` unlike for `clicked`, for which the documentation also says should have no effect but it most certainly does.

Furthermore, even if you make the top mouse area smaller, you will be able to register the cursor entering for both, but position changes will only register for the top-most mouse area that is under the cursor.

I wouldn't say that such functionality is an unreasonable feature, so you might want to file a bug report with a request to fix it so that you can get "common sense" behavior. However, such a fix will likely not come any time soon, if ever.

Depending on your actual usage scenario there might be some workarounds possible.

Worst case scenario, you can always have one single mouse area for the entire application window and manually propagate events to underlying objects, it is really not as tedious as it may sound, various similar limitations in the way things work in QML has driven me to do exactly that for both mouse and keyboard events.